# No matching function when using cmath functions with elements of get_continuous_state_vector()

Tags: drake

In my `DoCalcTimeDerivative`, I need to take cos for one of the state vector elements.

I do this with the following code

```
Vector4<T> x = context.get_continuous_state_vector().CopyToVector();
T c0 = std::cos(x[0]);
```

However, I get the following error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘cos(Eigen::DenseCoeffsBase<Eigen::Matrix<Eigen::AutoDiffScalar<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >, 4, 1, 0, 4, 1>, 1>::Scalar&)’
```

I've also tried using

```
const systems::VectorBase<T>& x = context.get_continuous_state_vector();
T c0 = std::cos(x[0]);
```

which similarly gives the following error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘cos(const Eigen::AutoDiffScalar<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1> >&)’
```

This is strange as I see `std::cos` and `std::sin` used in the examples but I can't seem to figure out why it works in the examples but not mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead:

```
using std::cos;
Vector4<T> x = context.get_continuous_state_vector().CopyToVector();
T c0 = cos(x[0]);
```

Comment: Adding link to concept (just for funsies): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup